# OpenSSL CSR using multiple SAN, and Extended Key Usage

Tags: openssl, csr

I am new to this. My objective is to create a CSR for my Cisco Firewall. I have been suggested to use OpenSSL as I need to add the EKU which is not possible on Cisco CSR. The second requirement is to use multiple SANs.

I have no clue how to do this and I don't know how or where I would generate the key (Cisco or OpenSSL). I have OpenSSL on both Linux and MacOS. Can someone post step-by-step instructions for me to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 5):

For SAN's and EKU's in OpenSSL:

- Generate the key: 
  `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`
- Create a config file (cisco_fw_csr_config.cnf) according to your needs:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
   
[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = BE
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Brussels
localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = Brussels
organizationalUnitName = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
commonName = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max = 64
emailAddress = Email Address
emailAddress_max = 40
    
[v3_req] 
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
    
[alt_names]
DNS.1   = san.domain1.com
DNS.2   = san.domain2.com
```

- Create the CSR:
  `openssl req -new -key key.pem -out cisco_fw.csr -config cisco_fw_csr_config.cnf`
- If you need to check the CSR content:
  `openssl req -in cisco_fw.csr -noout -text`

Comment: hi Seb,Thank you very much for your reply. It was very helpful. I have a few questions to ask you on this. How do I specify here the duration for certificate, so for example, if I want it for 3 years. Or does it have to be specified by the CA when they issue it? I was checking some other links and there are few other fields mentioned.   Is there any particular requirement for "basicConstraints" "nonRepudiation" and "dataEncipherment" . I have it like below:

[v3_req] 
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment

Comment: _How do I specify here the duration for certificate?_
You're right! The CA will be the one defining the certificate validity period.
_Is there any particular requirement for "basicConstraints" "nonRepudiation" and "dataEncipherment"?_
You just have to set the "features" that you need.
**basicConstraints=CA:FALSE** (The certificate can't issue/sign other certificates), is a good practice for end user ceritifcates.

Comment: It would be great if you included a reference for further reading

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate the csr without openssl asking you for the input values, you need to specify -batch option too.

```
openssl req -new -batch -key key.pem -out cisco_fw.csr -config cisco_fw_csr_config.cnf
```